# In Boolean algebra is X.(Y.Z) = (X.Y).(X.Z)

Tags: boolean, algebra

I know that `X.(Y+Z) = X.Y+X.Z` but does `X.(Y.Z) = (X.Y).(X.Z)` is true?

Please give me help.

Comment: wrong board. go to stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: SO is for programming questions. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean algebra and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a computer programming question.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is. X.(Y.Z) = (X.Y).(X.Z). Because X.X=X, one X on the RHS can be removed and we end up with the LHS.
(X.Y).(X.Z) = (X.X).(Y.Z) = (X).(Y.Z) = X.(Y.Z) 
You can draw a truth table and verify it yourself.

Comment: Assuming that `.` means multiply, `X.X` is not `X`. It is `X^2`. 2*2 doesn't equal 2.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley I hope you know what you're talking about. The question was about Boolean algebra, not ordinary algebra. In ordinary algebra, $X.X = X^2$ where $.$ is the multiplication operator. In Boolean algebra, $X.X = X$, where $.$ is the AND operator. Multiplication is **analogous** to AND operation in Boolean algebra. And as per your example, $2.2$ is $4$ in ordinary algebra, but in Boolean algebra $2.2 = 2$.

Comment: I had completely missed the “boolean” part of the question. Fair enough.